# How to display two dynamic spline charts on one page?

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I just learned about creating dynamic charts using highcharts. I need help, i'm trying to make a dynamic spline chart with data from php like [this](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data) (number 2). Then I try to create a dynamic spline chart under it (different div) by varying the data in php. But the results only show the chart below (chart B), on chart A does not display data as before B chart added. I asked, how to make two dynamic spline charts on one page? thank you

This is the code that I use

```
<?php //PHP for Chart A
// Set the JSON header
header("Content-type: text/json");

// The x value is the current JavaScript time, which is the Unix time multiplied 
// by 1000.
$x = time() * 1000;
// The y value is a random number
$y = rand(0, 100);

// Create a PHP array and echo it as JSON
$ret = array($x, $y);
echo json_encode($ret);
?>

<?php //PHP for Chart B
// Set the JSON header
header("Content-type: text/json");

// The x value is the current JavaScript time, which is the Unix time multiplied 
// by 1000.
$x = time() * 1000;
// The y value is a random number
$y = rand(100, 200);

// Create a PHP array and echo it as JSON
$ret = array($x, $y);
echo json_encode($ret);
?>
```

this is javascript code:

```
//JS of Chart A
var chart;
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dataChartA.php',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is 
                                                 // longer than 20

            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    chart = Highcharts.chart('chartA', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart A'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            title: {
                text: 'Value',
                margin: 80
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Chart A',
            data: []
        }]
    });        
});


//JS for Chart B
var chart;
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dataChartB.php',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is 
                                                 // longer than 20

            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    chart = Highcharts.chart('chartB', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart B'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            title: {
                text: 'Value B',
                margin: 80
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Chart B',
            data: []
        }]
    });        
});
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartA"></div>
<div id="chartB"></div> 
</body>
```

Results in the browser : https://i.stack.imgur.com/y96WC.jpg

Comment: You are using the same `chart` variable for both charts. I suggest you name them `chartA` and `chartB`.

Comment: thank you, now successfully displaying two charts on one page, variable chart and requestData on the JS chartA, I change to chartA and requestDataA as well as to JS for chartB.